# Opening book for stockfish

Tags: opening, stockfish

I am looking for a relatively up to date opening book for stockfish5 chess engine. I do not need it to be created by a stockfish team (only to work together with stockfish).

Up till now the only thing I was able to find is [really old book](http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/questions/767-opening-book) (it was updated during the time of version 2).

Is there anything newer?

Comment: Stockfish uses an open Polyglot book format. A simple google for "Polyglot chess book" will returns interesting results.

Comment: @StudentT thank you. Did no know about polyglot format. Actually was not able to find a normal book based on similar to yours searches (the best one was 1.4Mb, whereas my old stockfish book is 5.8mb).

Comment: The best chess books are designed for the Chessbase and Hiarcs format. The largest Polyglot books are usually bundled with a chess engine. I don't want to search every engine site, but I have seen it. You could build your own book. It's easy, this way you can turn a 100GB database into a gigantic book.

Answer (score 2):

This github post has links to polyglot books; the Komodo book looks especially enticing to me: https://github.com/michaeldv/donna_opening_books

Direct link to Komodo downloads: http://komodochess.com/downloads.htm

Comment: These books are for Donna, not Stockfish

Comment: Actually, books (as long as the correct format is used) are cross compatible with any engine. So, Stockfish should be able to use it no problem.